# How do I extract a RPG Maker MV HTML5 game out of Kongregate?

Tags: html, file, browser, rpgmakermv, kongregate

How do I extract a RPG Maker MV HTML5 game out of Kongregate, to help answer [a question on Arquade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/362322/108916)?

I know [how to extract](https://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/4wgkq0/is_there_any_way_to_download_a_game_from/) a regular HTML5 game, but it doesn't get me the files I need if I try that with the RPG Maker MV HTML5 game in question, [Medieval Shorts 3](https://www.kongregate.com/games/vasantj/medieval-shorts-3).

Instead, I get tons of Javascript and one CSS file, along with the HTML.

And the download link is dead, so this is the only way to get the music info without playing for about 50 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

That's simple, Just use the "Developer Tools" built-in in your browser.

Open the Game, Go to the Developer Tools and Go to the "Network" Section.

And just playing, Until the Music plays, You should can see the file shows up in  the Developer Tools, just Open it and Save it.

Comment: So *Close*! But I'm talking about the whole game, in a way I can play locally, and this question was asked because I want to avoid having to play through the whole thing. ... Not that *that* worked out, having spent more time here than I would've needed button-mashing.